# Why is the response structure not shown?

Tags: flask, swagger, flask-restful

I'm using `flask` with `Flask-RESTPlus`

It seems that the response of `get` is not shown in the generated json swagger file.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
import json

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Api(app = flask_app,
          version = "1.0",
          title = "test",
          description = "Test")

name_space = app.namespace('Actions part II', description='Teachers Actions')

model = app.model('Name Model',
                  {'name': fields.String(required = True, description="Test", help="Test help...")})
list_of_names = {'1':'abc', '2':'def', '3':'ghi'}
@name_space.route("/")
class MainClass(Resource):

    @app.doc(responses={200: 'OK', 400: 'Invalid Argument', 500: 'Mapping Key Error'})
    def get(self):
        try:
            print(json.dumps(app.__schema__))
            return {
                "status": "Person retrieved",
                "name" : list_of_names
            }
        except KeyError as e:
            name_space.abort(500, e.__doc__, status = "Could not retrieve information", statusCode = "500")
        except Exception as e:
            name_space.abort(400, e.__doc__, status = "Could not retrieve information", statusCode = "400")




def main():
    flask_app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And the generated json file:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "basePath": "/",
  "paths": {
    "/Actions part II/": {
      "get": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Invalid Argument"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "Mapping Key Error"
          }
        },
        "operationId": "get_main_class2",
        "tags": [
          "Actions part II"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "info": {
    "title": "Amitli test flask",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test flask architecutre with swagger"
  },
  "produces": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "consumes": [
    "application/json"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Actions part II",
      "description": "Teachers Actions"
    }
  ],
  "responses": {
    "ParseError": {
      "description": "When a mask can't be parsed"
    },
    "MaskError": {
      "description": "When any error occurs on mask"
    }
  }
}
```

The response from the app is:

```
{
  "status": "Person retrieved",
  "name": {
    "1": "abc",
    "2": "def",
    "3": "ghi"
  }
}
```

But I can't find this structure ( "status", "name") in the json file.

What am I missing ?